# Open Layers Generar Poligonos Mapas

Tags: openlayers

Buenas tardes estoy generando poligonos en un mapa con OpenLayers. Las coordenadas las obtengo con un web method de la base de datos y genero arrays de coordenadas a utilizarse en los poligonos.

[image: Coordenadas]

El problema que tengo es al momento de ejecutar el siguiente código:

```
 var poly = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([coordenadas.map(({lng, lat})=>[lng, lat])])
 })
```

[image: Error]

Y en chrome obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: Array]
Y no se cuál pueda ser el error. Por su ayuda muchas gracias.

```
    function generarMapas(){

    var FechaInicial='';
    var FechaFinal='';
    var Finca='';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FrmMapaAvanceRiego.aspx\/FillMapas",
        data: '{FechaInicial: "' + FechaInicial + '", FechaFinal: "' + FechaFinal + '", Finca: "' + Finca + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var data = JSON.parse(msg.d);
                coordenadas = [];
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                coordenadas[i] = item.Coordenadas;
                crearPoligonos(coordenadas[i]);
            });
        },
        error: errores
    });

  }

  function errores(msg) {
    alert('Error: ' + msg.responseText);
  }

  function crearPoligonos(coordenada) {

    var coordenadas = coordenada.split(' ') // Separamos por espacio
.map(function (data) {
    var info = data.split(','), // Separamos por coma
        coord = { // Creamos el obj de coordenada
            lat: parseFloat(info[1]),
            lng: parseFloat(info[0])
        };
    return coord;
});
console.log(coordenadas);
var parserJSTS = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();

var poly = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([coordenadas.map(({lng, lat})=>[lng, lat])])
})

}
```

Comment: El error parece ser porque llames a la función generarMapas desde un ámbito donde no está definida esa función.

Comment: Pero solo me da el error al ejecutar esta linea var poly = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([coordenadas.map(({lng, lat})=>[lng, lat])])
}) Si no está no da ningún problema.

Comment: Si tu navegador no soporta ES6, no puedes usar las arrow functions. Es lo único que se me ocurre. De todas formas, veo que en Chrome no te salta ningún error. (Muestras por consola la feature)

Comment: Si ese era el problema, si puedes ponlo como respuesta.